# Migration Error on Heroku with Postgres and Monetize

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku

I have a RoR 5.1 app that I am trying to deploy to Heroku.

In my gem file I specify the gem ‘pg’ for production. I also include the gem ‘money-rails’. In my database/migration files I have a few lines to create a field of the “monetize” type, which I understand should be handled by including the ‘money-rails’ gem.

When I deploy the app I don’t get any issues raised, but then when I go to migrate the db to create the tables I get the following error:

> ```
> StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
>
> PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "monetize" does not exist
> : ALTER TABLE "plans" ALTER COLUMN "price" TYPE monetize
> (followed by additional error lines)
> ```

Any idea on how to resolve this? Is there a gem I need to add? Is there something that needs to be updated/installed on Heroku? I’m not sure if there is a way to ignore having these specific migrations executed as they are not necessary for the codebase.

I could write a migration to drop the table, but that would only occur after it tries to create it, so not sure what the work around is.

Per the comments, here is the migration that created one of the tables in question: Plans

```
class CreatePlans < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :plans do |t|
      t.string :payment_gateway_plan_identifier
      t.string :name
      t.float :price
      t.integer :interval
      t.integer :interval_count
      t.integer :status
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And then here is the Change that I made to implement "monetize":

```
class ChangePriceToMonetizeInPlans < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    change_column :plans, :price, :monetize
  end
end
```

Also per the comments, monetize isn't a supported PG type, apparently. But since I've already created the migration (I use SQL lite 3 for my development), I'm not sure how to walk this back and remove it, since I assume that the migrations go in order. Sorry but this migration stuff (and rails in general) is still new to me.

Comment: Could you share the migration that's failing? The one that creates the `monetize` type?

Comment: There is [no type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype.html) "monetize" in Postgres. Did you mean `money`? [You shouldn't use that](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_money) - use `numeric` instead

Comment: i'm not certain if there is an installation task, or if i need to run bundle install on Heroku? I thought just deploying to heroku via git automatically runs bundle install.